# Quotient field of Polynomial ring over prime ideal is field of rational function over the prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading a book about Algebraic geometry and, I met the problem in context of transcendental extension.

Let $K$ be a field, $P$ be a prime ideal in polynomial ring $K[X_1,...,X_n]$, and L = quotient field of $K[X_1,...,X_n]/P$.

Then, I don't know how L is it. I'm not good at about quotient ring.
I know just the definition of the quotient ring and some examples.

Is it $ K(X_1,...,X_n)/P$ If so, how can I show it?

($K(X_1,...,X_n)$ is a quotient field of $K[X_1,...,X_n]$.)

The book then continues that transcendence degree of $L/K$ is finite... (assuming $Tr.d_K \mathbb{C} = \infty)$ but I am not sure because of this point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L/K$ has finite transcendence degree from Noether normalization lemma: $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/K$ is a algebra of finite type over the field $K$ and is a domain so its fraction field has finite transcendence degree equals to the Krull dimension of $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ which is $n$.

Comment: I got $K[X_1,...,X_n]/P$ is an algebra of finite type over the field $K$ and is an integral domain, so transcendence degree of its fraction field is equals to the Krull dimension of $K[X_1,...,X_n]/P$, by Noether normalization lemma. I'm now wondering is it equals to n?

Comment: It can be shown that the Krull dimension of $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is $n$ which seems so obvious but is not so easy to prove. As a result the Krull dimension of $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/P$ is smaller than $n$ (it can be strictly smaller, for example it is 0 if $P$ is maximal).

Comment: Thank you for your sincere answer. I understand now.